# Where I can see how many messages I published via Amazon SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon SNS as free tier, so it is limited 10,000 messages/month and I don't see anywhere to monitor this number.

Is there anywhere I can see this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two places you obtain information about your Amazon SNS usage:

**Amazon CloudWatch**

Amazon CloudWatch provides metrics information about the services run in AWS. For SNS, it provides metrics on **the number of messages published, delivered and failed** for each SNS topic.

See AWS documentation: [Monitoring Amazon SNS with CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/MonitorSNSwithCloudWatch.html)

**Free Usage Tier**

If you are eligible for the free tier and using a free tier offering, you can track your usage with the **Top Free Tier Services by Usage** table on the dashboard of the Billing and Cost Management console.

See AWS documentation: [Tracking Your Free Tier Usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/tracking-free-tier-usage.html)

Comment: Are copies of past messages stored anywhere? First time using it and figured there'd be a history or similar when viewing the topic in the browser, but can't spot any?

Comment: No. Amazon SNS does not store messages. You could, however, subscribe something to the Topic that records the message (eg an AWS Lambda function that stores it in a DynamoDB table or Amazon S3 object).